# Impala: set a constant date for timestamp

Tags: sql, impala

is there an alternative to the to_char() function in impala? I want to set a timestamp field where the date and minutes are fixed and only showing the hours, but can't seem to find an alternative.

This is my existing code in postgres which I need to convert to impala.

```
select to_char(starttime, '1900-01-01 HH24:00:00')::timestamp
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Impala, you can use

```
SELECT hours_add('1900-01-01', hour(now()));
```

to get the same result

- function `hour` extracts the hour part from a timestamp
- function `hours_add` adds hour to a timestamp